# Custom Control Same Assembly - Visual Web Part

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I am working on a Visual Web Part which requires creating a custom control. I am trying to **add custom control to the same assembly** as Visual Web Part and registering control as:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cus" Namespace="SomeCustomControlNameSpace" %>
```

When I am trying to access this its throwing runtime error :

Unknown server tag 'cus:ControlName'.

Do I need to make any Web.Config entry for this?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you've already tried this (and are tired of hearing it), but I've gotten this scenario to work by using the assembly tag to reference itself. My project is a web application so this might not work for a web site project. Anyway, here is my web application properties:

[image: Web Application Properties. Assembly name is: Example.Web]

On my page, in the same assembly, I have the following Register directive:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="jb" Namespace="CustomControlNameSpace" assembly="Example.Web" %>
```

As a side note, here is what [Microsoft says about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1(v=VS.90).aspx) (which doesn't mention what I tried above):

> When you use the @ Register directive
>   to reference a control, you can place
>   the code for the control in the
>   following places:
>
> - As source code in the application's
>     App_Code folder, where it will be
>     dynamically compiled at run time. This
>     is a convenient option during
>     development. If you choose this
>     option, you do not use the assembly
>     attribute in the @ Register directive.
> - As a compiled assembly in the
>     application's Bin folder. This is a
>     common option for deployed Web
>     applications.
> - As a compiled and signed assembly in
>     the global assembly cache (GAC). This
>     is a common option if you want to
>     share a compiled control among
>     multiple applications. You can
>     reference a control in the GAC by
>     assigning an identifying string to the
>     assembly attribute. The string
>     specifies the required details about
>     the control, including its fully
>     qualified type name, its version, its
>     public key token, and its culture.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell register which assembly to look at.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cus" Namespace="SomeCustomControlNameSpace" Assembly="SomeCustomControlAssembly" %>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am not missing Assembly attribute, but I have removed it as the class file for customControl is in same assembly as the WebPart. I CANNOT specify the assembly name or compiler will start yelling at me.